# How to get boolean value in firebase realtime database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a realtime database that im using in flutter.
I assign the firebase authentication key as the key for each user.
this is a snapshot of the database

```
"user": {
    "uFkR1Z1UoVTVUmbpDmgU7BXGT852": {
      "admin": true,
      "email": "****",
      "fullName": "ziad212",
      "phoneNo": "011111111"
    }
  }
```

I need to get the boolean value in admin node.

I have tried the following but it always give me false and the value does not change.
(User.isAdmin is a static bool value for the current session)

```
static isAdmin()async{
  if(AuthenticationRepository.auth.currentUser?.uid !=null){

  var currentId = AuthenticationRepository.auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final  snapshot =await database.ref('user/$currentId/admin').get();
  
  User.isAdmin =snapshot.value as bool;
  
  }
}
```

I have also tried Querying the whole user into a map and trying to access the value admin but still the same result
what am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code to get and handle the value looks fine at first glance. What happens if you hardcode the UID, i.e. `database.ref('user/uFkR1Z1UoVTVUmbpDmgU7BXGT852/admin').get()`?

Comment: Tried it but still the bool value is not updated

Comment: Hmmm.... it sounds like your code may not be looking at the same data then. It might be time to break out the debugger, and try to read for example the root of the database to see if that gives you any result.